# .gitignore still tracks file even after removing cache

Tags: git

I have my `.gitignore` file in `root/.gitignore`. I want to ignore a folder/directory that is in `root/path/to/folder`. In my `.gitignore` I have `root/path/to/folder`.

I've done

```
git rm --cached path/to/folder
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
```

But then I go back and change a file in that folder, then when I do git status, it shows up as modified.

Why is git not ignoring this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ignore the folder by adding a trailing slash in your `root/.gitignore` file:

```
root/path/to/folder/
```

And first, remove those files with a `rm -r`:

```
git rm --cached -r path/to/folder
```

Finally, make sure `folder` (in `path/to/folder`) is not a git repository itself (has no `.git` in it).
Because if `folder/.git` did exist, that would make folder a nested repo, and `.gitignore` rules in *parent* directories would have no bearing on its content.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with the -r options . git rm -r --cached path/to/folder . And if it is still showing , try git reset <>

Comment: Yes, I suggested that in my answer as well before.

Comment: Appreciate that , when i looked into it , there was no answers, so i posted one.